# scipy curve_fitting uses xdata array wrong

Tags: python, scipy

When I try call curve_data
Like so:

```
curve_fit(func, xdata=np.arange(50), ydata=some_array)
```

It calls func using all xdata at once ( the whole array) instead of e.g. the first element of the xadata (xdata[0])

What is happening.

Cheers.

Comment: What is wrong about it? It does exactly [what it says on the package.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)

Answer (score 0):

For people who happen to come across this: Scipy uses broadcasting, meaning if you use a math function in the function your are trying to fit, it also has to work with broadcasting, which basically means it internally loops over input vectors using c which is more efficient than looping in python. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html

For me the problem was, that I used the math library which does not support this.

Comment: Have a look at your question. If you knew only what is written there, would you come up with this answer? You do not even mention your curve fit function that causes this problem. I hope you will draw some conclusions for your next questions from this experience. Please read again [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The function did not matter at all. Someone who knows that broadcasting is used internally could have said, that this is indeed normal. And someone did in the Comment, that helped a lot. So I am quite happy.